# How to check the time corresponding to the maximum value of certain time period in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: sql, database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

```sql
select extreme(DDS09) from root,22,B78624018 
where time >= 1675240584000 and time <= 1675240704000
```

When I use this following query statement:

```sql
select extreme(DDS09) from root,22,B78624018 
where time >= 1675240584000 and time <= 1675240704000
```

I can get the maximum data value during this period of time in Apache IoTDB. However, I also need to find the corresponding time of this maximum value. Wonder how should I write the query statement to find this timestamp in IoTDB ?

Does any one can deal this problem？Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the timestamp and the value of this maximum number by changing the order of query statement a bit, switching the "max" qualification to the end of the statement, so the result of the statement will be the whole time series of this maximum value in Apache IoTDB (including the timestamp).

Try to use below case to see if you get your answer.

```
select DDS09 from root,22,B78624018 where time >= 1675240584000 and time <= 1675240704000 and DDS09 = max_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAX_TIME()` - but as I haven't actually used this try both variants seen below. I don't think you will need to nest the functions, but try it anyway:

```
SELECT MAX_TIME(EXTREME(DDS09)) , MAX_TIME(DDS09) , EXTREME(DDS09)
FROM root.22.B78624018 
WHERE time >= 1675240584000 AND time <= 1675240704000
```

ref: https://iotdb.apache.org/UserGuide/Master/Operators-Functions/Aggregation.html